# How to improve this question on claims that the liberal media prevents anti-government reporting

Tags: support, closed-questions

I hear this all the time.  Last night during a bout of insomnia, I flipped to Fox Business and saw Stossel complaining about how the "liberal media" *almost* totally forbids reports on problems with government.

I decided to find the blog post that corresponds to this episode if it existed, luckily it did, and I used it as the source of the claim for [this question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/22321/do-non-conservative-us-media-organizations-discourage-reporting-criticizing-gove).

Granted, he definitely dances around the claim, but the implication seems pretty clear.  Should I find a direct quote?  Should these quotes be removed?

Also, this claim, of course, comes from the right and calls everything not conservative and sometimes not libertarian as "the liberal media".  This seems like a confusing, partisan claim since the major networks were gung ho on Iraq before the invasion, which could make one believe that they are some kind of combination of populist and cheerleader for whoever's in power.

Should this question be totally rewritten to express the above intent?

What public claims should be used to express the above intent?

Answer (score 2):

I see a number of issues related to this question that need to be addressed:

- Stossel's web-site is poorly written. It isn't clear at all what he is claiming. The page jumps all over the place, and it never seems to stick to a point. I am not familiar with his normal style, but this makes it tricky. I don't agree with you when you say "the implication is clear"; I didn't get it.
- You seem to have interpreted the claim to apply to all "liberal media". I don't know where you got that from. He seems to be talking about only CBS (and perhaps Channel 2 News? I don't know who they are.)
- If the definition of "liberal media" is media that declines to run anti-government stories at the same rate as an openly-biased Fox reporter would prefer, then we have a tautology. If it isn't, we have a missing definition.

Note: I am not claiming that there are not pro-government biases in some media outlets (and anti-government biases in some others). I think that is pretty obviously true after reading a newspaper (or even looking at a single choice of illustrative photo of the politicians.) I think that bias is applied in a number of different ways at a number of different organisational levels. Which makes the question even more confusing to me. Are you skeptical that liberal-biased media are biased toward a liberal (by US standards) government?

I'm not sure what any of this has to do with the invasion of Iraq.